# docker: Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit

Tags: docker

Делал все как обычно, но после установки докера при выполнении команды `docker run hello-world`

Выдается ошибки о превышении какого то лимита. Хотя я еще не авторизовался нигде. Это связано с тем, что по этому ip адресу скачивается много образов?

> sudo docker run hello-world Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest'
> locally docker: Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests: You have
> reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by
> authenticating and upgrading:
> https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit. See 'docker run --help'.

Comment: да, по ссылке об этом и написано, с конца ноября - `Anonymous and Free Docker Hub users are limited to 100 and 200 container image pull requests per six hours.`, правда вы только установили докер, возможно это связано с тем, что вы сидите за nat и все кто входит эту подсеть регистрируются как один пользователь, попробуйте залогиниться под своим акком, может поможет

Comment: ну у меня аккуант есть, я на сайт вошел в него в браузере. Или надо в в другом месте войти?

Comment: ещё можно в докере логиниться через `docker login` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/